Is it possible to cancel a pending purchase via Google Play Developer API without order ID?
My app currently cancels pending purchases via orders.refund endpoint. However, in the v6 version of Google Play Billing API, pending purchases no longer have an order ID. Is there any way to cancel a pending purchase programmatically without an order ID?
